# The greatest lower bound of $|\cos(x)+\sin(x)|$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

I was going through a problem when I stumbled across the need to find the **infimum** of :
$$|\cos(x)+\sin(x)|$$
where $x\in \mathbb R$.
[image]

It is easy to get a **lower bound**, for we must have $|\cos(x)+\sin(x)|>0$ as $|cos(x)|\ge 0$ and $|sin(x)|\ge 0$. But intuitively it makes sense to say that the **infimum** would be some positive real number, as $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ won't reduce down to zero for the same $x$.

The existence of the **infimum** is guaranteed by the completeness of the reals. But how do I find it. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use Desmos to plot $\cos(x)+ \sin(x) $ then you'll immediately that the sum *is* zero for some $x$.

Comment: $\sin x + \cos x = \sqrt 2\sin (x +\frac \pi4) = \sqrt2 \cos (x -\frac \pi4)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$|\cos x +\sin x|^{2}=1+2\cos x \sin x=1+\sin 2x$. The infimum of $|\cos x +\sin x|^{2}$ is, therfore, $0$. This implies that the infimum of $|\cos x +\sin x|$ is also $0$. It is, in fact, attained at $x=\frac {3\pi} 4$.